# Couldn't find Customer without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I've got a very simple app where the flow looks like this:

User reads some copy, decides they want to purchase the product and fill out the form, see confirmation page.

Something is wrong in my controller but I can't quite pinpoint it where I'm getting the error `Couldn't find Customer without an ID.`

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
#  before_filter :load_customer, :only => :show

  def new
    @customer = Customer.new
  end

  def create
    @customer = Customer.new(params[:customer])

    if @customer.save
      session[:customer_id] = @customer.id
      purchase
    else
      flash[:error] = "Please enter a valid email address"
      redirect_to :signup
    end
  end

  def signup
    @customer = Customer.new
  end


  def purchase
    Stripe.api_key = STRIPE['secret']
    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :amount => 2000,
    :currency => "usd",
    :card => params[:stripe_token],
    :description => "My Product Name"
    )
    redirect_to receipt_path
  end

  def receipt
    @customer = Customer.find(session[:customer_id])

    @name = @customer.name
    @email = @customer.email
    @product = @customer.product
  end

  # private
  # 
  # def load_customer
  #   @customer = Customer.find(session[:customer_id])
  #   redirect_to request.path.gsub(params[:id], session[:customer_id].to_s) if params[:id] != session[:customer_id].to_s
  # end

end
```

I'm not sure where things are screwing up and after much Googling, I'm turning to you guys. Help would be huge.

EDIT:

Consulting with Rails console shows that my application isn't making new customer records for some reason. Charging *is* working, however. Customers not being created must be a precursor to this.

EDIT 2: Development.log

```
Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-28 15:58:11 -0700
Served asset /bootstrap.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2012-08-28 15:58:11] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started POST "/checkout" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-28 15:58:12 -0700
Processing by CustomersController#purchase as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"k2aW/CAkNfwDSMHHvzbuOwm+Xua0qb2LJ4LtrtRvyvk=", "customer"=>{"name"=>"Your name", "email"=>"yourname@example.com"}, "stripe_token"=>"tok_0GUvwKPwo6jfEu"}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/receipt
Completed 302 Found in 1064ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/receipt" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-28 15:58:14 -0700
Processing by CustomersController#receipt as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Customer without an ID):
  app/controllers/customers_controller.rb:38:in `receipt'


  Rendered /Users/zack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@beat-the-herd/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (3.9ms)
  Rendered /Users/zack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@beat-the-herd/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (5.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/zack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@beat-the-herd/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (23.7ms)
```

Comment: Could you please submit the development log in full from the moment you go to signup to the moment you call purchase? That would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user routes directly to `receipt` action then `session[:customer_id]` may be nil. That's why you get the error. This is not happened if a `create` (possibly) POST request is issued. In this case, the session variable has been populated before the redirection to the `receipt` action.

Comment: This is exactly what's happening I think. Since my form starts `<%= form_for @customer, :url => purchase_path, :method  => :post do |f| %>`

Comment: How would you recommend that I remedy this so that the user is created, then charged, then shown their receipt?

Comment: The problem is that you POST to `purchase_path` where the `session[:customer_id] = @customer.id` is not executed :)!

Comment: How would you recommend that I fix this?

Comment: I believe you should separate the logic of creation and purchase things. Think all the possible state transitions and then implement the actions.

Answer (score 0):

This line :

```
@customer = Customer.find(session[:customer_id])
```

throws an error because session[:customer_id] is nil

You might want to use find_by_id that won't throw an Exception but will return an nil record.

Then you'll have to deal with the case of @customer being nil.

Comment: When I look in my rails console, it looks like the customer isn't actually being created which is what might be causing this. Any idea why?

Comment: @customer.save returns true ?

Comment: @customer.save is returning true, I believe, because the purchase method is being called successfully

Comment: try to log the value of session[:customer_id] after setting it.

Maybe your browser does not accept cookies so the session is not set when going to the receipt action ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in UserController

```
def show <br>
@user = User.find(session[:user_id])<br>
@profile = @user.profile<br>
end
```

Rather than putting "user_id" put session[:user_id] 
It worked for me